# file_get_contents missing <img> tag inside <td>

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch `HTML` content using `file_get_contents`. Everything i working as expected, its just that /,img> tag is not being fetched.

Please have a look at my `PHP` code::

```php
<?php    
$dom = new DOMDocument();  

//load the html  
$remote  = file_get_contents('test.htm');  
$tables = $dom->loadHTML($remote);
//discard white space   
//$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

//the table by its tag name  
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName("table");   

//  get all rows from the table  
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("tr"); 

// get each column by tag name  
$cols = $rows->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("th");   
$row_headers = NULL;
foreach ($cols as $node) {
    //print $node->nodeValue."\n";   
    $row_headers[] = $node->nodeValue;
}   

$table = array();

//get all rows from the table  
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("tr");   
foreach ($rows as $row)   
{   
    // get each column by tag name  
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName("td");   
    $row = array();
    $i=0;
    foreach ($cols as $node) {
        # code...

        if($row_headers==NULL)
            $row[] = $node->nodeValue;
        else
            $row[$row_headers[$i]] = $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML($node);
        $i++;
    }   
    $table[] = $row;
}  

// var_dump($table);
// extract($table);
// echo "<table>\n($table,true)\n</table>";
// echo ("$remote");
print("<pre>".print_r($table,true)."</pre>");
?>
```

And this is my `HTML` code which is being parsed.

```html
<table border="1" width="610" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="112">
            <p><span lang="EN-US">Question </span></p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" width="498">
            <p><strong><span lang="EN-US">Consider the following reaction,</span></strong></p>
            <p><strong><span lang="EN-US">H</span></strong><strong><sub><span
                    lang="EN-US">3</span></sub></strong><strong><span
                    lang="EN-US">C &ndash; CH &ndash; CH &ndash; CH</span></strong><strong><sub><span
                    lang="EN-US">3</span></sub></strong><strong><span lang="EN-US"> + </span></strong><strong><span
                    lang="EN-US"><img src="hydrocarbon2_files/image001.png" alt="" width="26"
                                      height="29"/></span></strong><strong><span lang="EN-US">&nbsp;&rarr; &lsquo;X&rsquo; + HBr </span></strong>
            </p>
            <p><strong><span lang="EN-US"> | |</span></strong></p>
            <p><strong><span lang="EN-US"> D CH</span></strong><strong><sub><span lang="EN-US">3</span></sub></strong>
            </p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="112">
            <p><span lang="EN-US">Type</span></p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" width="498">
            <p><span lang="EN-US">multiple_choice</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="112">
            <p><span lang="EN-US">Option::</span></p>
        </td>
        <td width="219">
            <p><img src="hydrocarbon2_files/image002.jpg" alt="" width="205" height="93"/></p>
        </td>
        <td width="279">
            <p><span lang="EN-US">I</span><span lang="EN-US">ncorrect</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="112">
            <p><span lang="EN-US">Option</span></p>
        </td>
        <td width="219">
            <p><img src="hydrocarbon2_files/image003.jpg" alt="" width="205" height="102"/></p>
        </td>
        <td width="279">
            <p><span lang="EN-US">C</span><span lang="EN-US">orrect</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="112">
            <p><span lang="EN-US">Option</span></p>
        </td>
        <td width="219">
            <p><img src="hydrocarbon2_files/image004.jpg" alt="" width="205" height="107"/></p>
        </td>
        <td width="279">
            <p><span lang="EN-US">Incorrect</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="112">
            <p><span lang="EN-US">Option</span></p>
        </td>
        <td width="219">
            <p><img src="hydrocarbon2_files/image005.jpg" alt="" width="205" height="112"/></p>
        </td>
        <td width="279">
            <p><span lang="EN-US">Incorrect</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="112">
            <p><span lang="EN-US">Solution</span></p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" width="498">
            <p><img src="hydrocarbon2_files/image006.jpg" alt="" width="398" height="92"/></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="112">
            <p><span lang="EN-US">Marks</span></p>
        </td>
        <td width="219">
            <p><span lang="EN-US">4</span></p>
        </td>
        <td width="279">
            <p><span lang="EN-US">1</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When PHP is fetching my code and showing me in Array, it is skipping the images, see the result below::
[image]

Kindly help me in achieving this. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that as you have no row headers (there are no `<th>` fields), then `$row_headers` will be empty.

So when you read the actual data from the table, the code

```
    if($row_headers==NULL)
        $row[] = $node->nodeValue;
    else
        $row[$row_headers[$i]] = $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML($node);
```

will always execute the first option and just get the value, which doesn't include any HTML.  If you change the code to store the HTML for the NULL option...

```
    if($row_headers==NULL)
        $row[] = $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML($node);
    else
        $row[$row_headers[$i]] = $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML($node);
```

you will get all of the `<td>` content.